# Возникает ошибка Warning: Illegal string offset 'key' при создании названия переменной

Tags: php, warning

В БД таблица media имеет структуру: id, attachment_url, title, alt
Делаем запрос SELECT * FROM `media`
Выводим через while:

```
$media_id = $media[id]
<img src=\"$media[attachment_url]\">
alt: <input type='text' name='$media_id[alt]' value='$media[alt]'>
title: <input type='text' name='$media_id[title]' value='$media[title]'>
```

При формировании каждого поля input возникает ошибка Warning: Illegal string offset 'alt' и ...'title'

Так работает:

```
alt: <input type='text' name='alt[$media_id]' value='$media[alt]'>
title: <input type='text' name='title[$media_id]' value='$media[title]'>
```

Если название полей input alt[$media_id] и title[$media_id], то данные передаются в двух массивах 'alt' и 'title', где значение поля input соответствует $media_id. Но это неудобно, так как будут еще МЕТА поля, текстовое описание для фото и прочее. Получается, что чтобы записать данные, мне необходимо каждый массив 'alt' и 'title' прогонять через цикл. Хотелось бы получить несколько массивов с названиями media_id с элементами, у которых ключи будут 'alt' и 'title'

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка возникает потому, что в вашем случае $media_id - это переменная с конкретным числовым значением: $media_id = $media[id] . Естественно, когда вы дальше пытаетесь вставить в свои инпуты $media_id[alt] или $media_id[title], в ответ получаете ошибку.

Судя по вашим потребностям, я бы предложил примерно такую конструкцию:

```
alt: <input type='text' name='media[$media_id][alt]' value='$media[alt]'>
title: <input type='text' name='media[$media_id][title]' value='$media[title]'>
```

В этом случае, после того, как вы отправите данные на сервер, у вас будет сформирован один массив $media, где элементы будут иметь свой индекс *id* и можно будет очень просто получить параметры *alt* и *title* , например `$media[id]['alt']` и `$media[id]['title']`.